# Spring Security 5 Stateless OAuth2 Login - how to implement cookies based AuthorizationRequestRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to have Google/Facebook login using Spring Security 5 OAuth2 login feature. But the problem I'm facing is that I'm coding a stateless API, whereas Spring security 5 uses `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository` to store authorization requests, which uses session. So, I thought not to use that and code a cookie based implementation, which looks as below:

```
public class HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository implements AuthorizationRequestRepository<OAuth2AuthorizationRequest> {

    private static final String COOKIE_NAME = "some-name";

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest loadAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");

        return fetchCookie(request)
                .map(this::toOAuth2AuthorizationRequest)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        Assert.notNull(request, "request cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(response, "response cannot be null");

        if (authorizationRequest == null) {

            deleteCookie(request, response);
            return;
        }

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(COOKIE_NAME, fromAuthorizationRequest(authorizationRequest));
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }


    private String fromAuthorizationRequest(OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {

        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(
                SerializationUtils.serialize(authorizationRequest));
    }

    private void deleteCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        fetchCookie(request).ifPresent(cookie -> {

            cookie.setValue("");
            cookie.setPath("/");
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest removeAuthorizationRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

        // Question: How to remove the cookie, because we don't have access to response object here.
        return loadAuthorizationRequest(request);
    }

    private Optional<Cookie> fetchCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        if (cookies != null && cookies.length > 0)
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
                if (cookies[i].getName().equals(COOKIE_NAME))
                    return Optional.of(cookies[i]);

        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest toOAuth2AuthorizationRequest(Cookie cookie) {

        return SerializationUtils.deserialize(
                Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(cookie.getValue()));
    }
}
```

The above basically stores the data in a cookie instead of session. I've a couple of questions:

1. How exactly to code the `removeAuthorizationRequest` method above? I wanted the cookie removed there, but we don't have access to the `response` object.
2. Does the above (cookie based) approach look okay? E.g. any security issues?

**Update**: Have created an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5313 . Until that's addressed, here is a workaround I came up with: https://www.naturalprogrammer.com/blog/1681261/spring-security-5-oauth2-login-signup-stateless-restful-web-services

Comment: Do you know why Spring keeps Information about the OAuth2AuthorizationRequest at all? Why would u need that?

Comment: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-2/ does implement such a stateless AuthorizationRequestRepository

Comment: But does not remove the cookies directly... he does so on failure and success and in the corresponding handlers